# C# Composite transform on a rectangle

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to move a rectangle when user drags it. My code is:

```
 private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
         Rectangle r = (sender) as Rectangle;
         r.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { TranslateX = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X };

    }
```

Above code doesn't work because it should be like this:

```
r.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X };
```

"+" sign makes it work but above syntax give an error. It works fine when I add Render transform using xaml but I want to do it in c#. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do not set a new RenderTransform in each call of the ManipulationDelta handler. Instead, assign some transform object once, and later only modify that one.

Comment: @Clemens how do I do that?

Comment: By casting the RenderTransform to a CompositeTransform.

Comment: @Clemens can you please show that in code? I am not getting it

Comment: `((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).TanslateX += ...`, given that `r.RenderTransform != null`

Comment: @BastiM I am getting this error: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform' to type 'System.Windows.Media.CompositeTransform'.

Comment: Then the RenderTransform is already a MatrixTransform...just like the message tells you. As @Clemens said: assign the CompositeTransform once.

Comment: @BastiM Thank you, it's working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting the solution proposed in the comments into an answer:

They way you did it was to assign a *new* CompositeTransform on every call of the event handler. This is not what you want. You want to manipulate an existing CompositeTransform instead.

In order to achieve this, you have to manually assign the `CompositeTransform` once *outside your eventhandler*:

```
r.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
```

After this you can use the following in your event handler:

```
((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have done translation and scaling successfully but afte scaling center of manipulation changes and it affects the translation, can you suggest something?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 My suggestion is to fix this... ;-) Honestly: you should ask a new question for this, explaining the exact behaviour and showing your code (how you scale etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326641/c-sharp-pinch-manipulation-center-changes

Comment: Please have look at above question, I want to know the solution, thanks again