# c# pinch manipulation center changes

Tags: c#

I am trying to use translation and pinch manipulations and both are working fine. Only problem is that after using pinch manipulation centre changes and translation manipulation doesn't work as expected.
My code:

```
void r_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
     Rectangle r = (sender) as Rectangle;

     ((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
     ((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;


     if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
     {
          ((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
          ((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform).ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
     }
 }
```

What should I do?

Comment: I would at the very least recommend you store `((CompositeTransform)r.RenderTransform)` as something to make your code less verbose and more readable.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use `as` then use members on it, you should either just cast (`Rectangle r = (Rectangle)sender;`) or check to see if it's null before doing anything.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Code is working fine, only I need to adjust the centre

Comment: I was offering suggestions, rather than solutions.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform(v=vs.95).aspx

The transforms are applied in order Scale, Skew, Rotate & then Translate.

If required you should set the centre properties before any of the transforms.

If you need a specific different order then the TransformGroup should be used & also if the centre points should be different for each transfom.